# Input Placeholder css not working in IE9

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Placeholder color not working in IE 9 only. Other browser working fine.
Can anybody tell me which css required for IE9? I used one  div -> select element -> default input field  .Want to change text color of place holder. I search on Google it will work on IE 10+

```css
input:-ms-input-placeholder    {
  color:#27AE60 !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="inputText" placeholder="somePlaceholder" />
```

### Original CSS selector:

```
 #dropdown_ID div.selectize-control div.selectize-input input:-ms-input-placeholder {
      color:#27AE60 !important;
  }
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=%3A%3Aplaceholder - this kind of answers it.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jaywilliams/1105055

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you are right. IE doesn't support placeholder attribute.
I found this two link useful to choose alternative for issue of placeholder in IE.

Referral link :

https://mathiasbynens.github.io/jquery-placeholder/ 
http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

You can use any way to solve your problem.